Having trouble building a Colpitts oscillator
I've build the following circuit on a copper clad board. It is supposed to be oscillating at about 58MHz or so. I can simulate it in LTSpice and it oscillates. However, it does not work on the real board.
What am I doing wrong? Am I too optimistic about BC547 running at 58MHz?
I've checked for the following:

no shorts
VCC is 8V
Checked Vb and Ve, the transistor is properly biased
Probed Vb and Ve with the oscilloscope


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Second layout


Nice PCB. || What is emitter voltage? || fT IS 300 mhZ which is OKish but gain will be under 10. || I'd tend to avoid biasing Si bipolar with a single R (Germanium was happy) but if you have checked Vb then should be OK. || Those leads have significant inductance - maybe in the 10 uH/cm range. Layout MAY be OK but the etra stray L may be causing issues.|| I suggest trying an inductor maybe 10 x as large and see if it oscillates and IF SO then reducing inductor to see where it fails. || Layout is very pretty but it would be easy to reduce lead lengths for caps and transistor. Try larger L 1st.

Wire selfinductance calculator https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/

@RussellMcMahon
Ve reads 5.60V
Vb reads 6.04V
But interestingly enough, if I measure Vbe it reads 0.632 which probably resonates with what you mentioned about biasing the transistor with a single R.

@Burglups
How do I test the impedance of resistors?
I've measured the resistance of each one before installing them, but not sure how I can test the impedance at the expected frequency.

C2 in photo says 100. Could this be $10 pf$ rather than 100 pf??. From you voltmeter measurements (thank you) I think it is oscillating, but at a much higher frequency, low amplitude, via unanticipated resonant paths... add a 10nf or 1nf capacitor from collector to GND as mentioned by @Burglups.

For this circuit working, I had to lower C3 to 10 nF, R1 to 47k and R2 to 1k.

A few pointers (given that I've used this circuit topology and a BC547 BJT running around 60 MHz but, everything was surface mount and tightly connected): -

Reduce the base bias resistor to around 22 kohm
Drop the emitter resistor to 1 kohm
Check the self-resonant-frequencies of those disc capacitors
Layout is poor for this type of oscillator running at 58 MHz
Make your 0 volt connection right at the ground terminal of your inductor
Check the self-resonant-frequency for the inductor is above 100 MHz
Shorten the leads of the capacitors
Add 10 nF and 1 nF parallel decoupling capacitors between supply rail and ground/0 volts

From memory, I believe I used an inductor of around 330 nH. The type was an 0805 surface mount of this type.

Are you happy with the single resistor bias or would you recommend changing to a resistive divider.?

I'm happy with that type of bias @RussellMcMahon <-- it's debatable but seems to work for most designs of this topology. I'm sure I've used a two resistor bias in the past but, I'm also sure I've used a single resistor too.

The board is double sided and the bottom copper layer is not connected to the top ground plane. Is this an additional issue?

@DanCorneanu it would be preferable to use the bottom copper as a full ground plane. Obviously this means drilling oversize holes to pass 0 volt connections through.

@Andyaka regarding the poor layout, is the second one better? (picture added to the original question)
I have drilled holes for 3 vias between top and bottom but only filled 2 of them with some copper wire and solder.

It's likely to be better but have you followed my guidelines?

I thought I should make one change at a time. If the layout looks better I'm going to change the resistor values.

@DanCorneanu - The second layout is better but still without any supply decoupling. The schematic as used for simulation is incomplete and mirroring it 1:1 in your layout will not work in real life. The caps in the capacitive divider are rather large for an oscillator working around 58MHz, which would make the negative resistance at the base probably to small for the given quality factor of the inductor used in the tank circuit.


I've added a 10uF + 1nF caps on the power suply to ground
lowered the base resistor to 22k
lowered the emitter resistor to 1K

It oscillates with a ~200mV pp on the base
Thanks @Andyaka

TLDR: Impedance from collector to ground must be low-impedance. That means adding a bypass capacitor from collector to the resonator's ground point.
OP's circuit runs transistor collector straight back to the DC voltage source through a long wire. In his SPICE simulation, collector is ensured to be steady DC, able to supply infinite current instantaneously. This simulation doesn't accurately replicate his circuit construction.
And so I've tried an LTspice simulation with more realistic components, and have added some lossy inductance to that long path back to the DC source (100nH with 10 ohms series resistance). 20nH has been added to all the capacitors to simulate their wire leads:

50 nH wire leads causes serious disruption to oscillator output. Yes, it does try to oscillate near 42 MHz, but also at a much higher frequency too...parasitic reactances cause mayhem up to half a gigahertz. Oscillation amplitude at the desired frequency is quite low, likely due to resonator component values.
It has been my experience that SPICE simulations oscillate readily, whereas breadboard construction oscillates less robustly. I'd like to blame imperfect transistor models, but I might be missing a critical parasitic reactance.

Re-biasing this circuit, with a few component changes yields higher voltage amplitude at the emitter. An attempt has been made to reduce parasitic effects...lead inductance of the capacitors has been reduced from 20nH to 4nH. Oscillation amplitude at the emitter is higher, however parasitic effects persist:

Choosing a faster transistor seems to push parasitics to a higher frequency. I suspect the pulse current amplitude would not reach quite so high (22mA), resulting in somewhat lower oscillating amplitude:

